# Update and delete object inside userDefaults by INDEX

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I am created 3 object and save each of this inside user defaults how I am can update not all data, are only object Number 3?

This is code how I am save and fetch data:

```
  func savePlayer(player: [Player]) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(player), forKey:"player")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
    
    func getSports() -> [Player]? {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"player") as? Data {
            let decodedSports = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode([Player].self, from: data)
            return decodedSports
        }
        return nil
    }
```

This is my objects:

```
let playerOne = Player(id: 1, url: "https:\\www.google - 1.com", color: "#color 1", image: "imageBase64One", flag: false, position: 1)

let playerTwo = Player(id: 2, url: "https:\\www.google - 2.com", color: "#color 2", image: "imageBase64Two", flag: false, position: 2)

let playerThree = Player(id: 3, url: "https:\\www.google - 3.com", color: "#color 3", image: "imageBase64Three", flag: false, position: 3)
```

Model of data:

```
class Player: Codable {
    let ID: Int
    let URL: String
    let Color: String
    let Image: String
    var Flag: Bool
    let Position: Int
    
    init(id: Int, url: String, color: String, image: String, flag: Bool, position: Int) {
        self.ID = id
        self.URL = url
        self.Color = color
        self.Image = image
        self.Flag = flag
        self.Position = position
    }
}
```

I can't understand how update for example option "flag" for second object and and also delete only object two not all.

Comment: When you call getSports you get an array of objects back so just treat it like any other array of objects and when done doing changes then call savePlayer again

Comment: Unrelated but never use `value(forKey` of `UserDefaults` to get `Data`. There is `data(forKey:`

Comment: Thank you for help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to set in your class the position of each item and no need to call UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() either since it's deprecated.

Anyway, whenever you want to edit an object from your array:

1. define your array and append your objects to it:

```
var myArray: [Player] = []!
```

2. call the position of the array you want to edit, if you want to edit the second object then:

```swift
myArray[2] =  Player(id: 15, url: "https:\\www.niceUrl.com", color: .black, image: "niceImage", flag: true, position: 2)
savePlayer(player: myArray[2])
```

Note that here I changed all of the values, if you just want to change one you can.